# why this metal code give me GPU Time OUT error?

Tags: ios, swift, metal

```
kernel void array_sum(device float *array,
                      device int &len,
                      uint index [[ thread_position_in_grid ]])
{
    int i = (index << 1);
    int j = i + 1;
    int k;
    while (isnan(array[i]) || isnan(array[j])) {
        k = i; i = j; j = k; // timeout
    }
    array[index + len] = array[i] + array[j];
}
```

this code does not work. If you run it forcibly, it will cause GPU Timeout, and there is even a chance that your computer will have a splash screen, UI misalignment, and black blocks on the screen.So,Why??

Comment: It is because you put a while loop in a Metal shader and it does not terminate. It is fine to have a loop in Metal code, but that really only works with a fixed number of iterations. Basically, you need to rethink you logic so that it can be processed correctly on a GPU.

Comment: thx 4 your help,I rewite my code,it can work now :p `{
    int i = index * interval << 1;
    array[i] += array[i + interval];
}'